# jquery / javascript to sum field only if checkbox on same row is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery / javascript function that totals the number of cubes in my order. this works 100% and is below.

```
function calculateTotalVolume() {
    var grandTotalCubes = 0;
    $("table.authors-list").find('input[name^="cubicvolume"]').each(function () {
        grandTotalCubes += +$(this).val();
    });
    $("#grandtotalcubes").text(grandTotalCubes.toFixed(2));
}
```

as mentioned the above works great. I need a second function to total the same field but only if an checkbox named treated is checked. each row has the checkbox named treated but as the table is dynamically generated, a counter is appended to the name each time hence my use of `name^="treated"`

I am after something like below but this doesn't work:

```
function calculateTotalTreatedVolume() {
    var grandTotaltreatedCubes = 0;
    $("table.authors-list").find('input[name^="cubicvolume"]').each(function () {
        if($("table.authors-list").find('checkbox[name^="treated"]').checked){
            alert('10');
            grandTotaltreatedCubes += +$(this).val();
    }

    });
    $("#grandtotaltreatedcubes").text(grandTotaltreatedCubes.toFixed(2));
}
```

help appreciated as always.

**UPDATE**

Rendered HTML output [1 dynamic row added]: (Still in development so very rough, please excuse it)

```
<table class="authors-list" border=1>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td></td><td>Product</td><td>Price/Cube</td><td>Qty</td><td>line total cost</td><td>Discount</td><td>Cubes per bundle</td><td>pcs per bundle</td><td>cubic vol</td><td>Bundles</td><td><input type="checkbox" class="checkall"> Treated</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td><a class="deleteRow"> <img src="http://devryan.tekwani.co.za/application/assets/images/delete2.png" /></a></td>
     <td><input type="text" id="product" name="product" />
     <input type="hidden" id="price" name="price" readonly="readonly"/></td>
     <td><input type="text" id="adjustedprice" name="adjustedprice" /></td>
     <td><input type="text" id="qty" name="qty" /></td>
     <td><input type="text" id="linetotal" name="linetotal" readonly="readonly"/></td>
     <td><input type="text" id="discount" name="discount" /></td>
     <td>
        <input type="text" id="cubesperbundle" name="cubesperbundle" >
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="pcsperbundle" name="pcsperbundle" >
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="cubicvolume" name="cubicvolume"  size='5' disabled>
    </td>
     <td><input type="text" id="totalbundles" name="totalbundles" size='5' disabled ></td>
    <td valign="top" ><input type="checkbox" id="treated" name="treated" ></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="15"><input type="button" id="addrow" value="Add Product" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">Grand Total: R<span id="grandtotal"></span></td>
        <td colspan="2">Ave Discount: <span id="avediscount"></span>%</td>
        <td colspan="1">Total Cubes: <span id="grandtotalcubes"></span></td>
        <td colspan="15">Treated Cubes: <span id="grandtotaltreatedcubes"></span></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="15"><textarea  rows="1" cols="50" placeholder="Specific Comments"></textarea><textarea  rows="1" cols="20" placeholder="Customer Reference"></textarea>
</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Its amazing how all the answerers (including me) didn't spot the invalid `checkbox` selector inside the `.find()` !!

Comment: probably giving me too much credit :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through the "checked" checkboxes using `$("table.authors-list").find('checkbox[name^="treated"]:checked')` and use the value of the input nearest to it (assumed to be in the same row).

Assuming your table has many rows each having a checkbox and an input, you can use:

```
function calculateTotalTreatedVolume() {
    var grandTotaltreatedCubes = 0;

    // iterate through the "checked" checkboxes
    $("table.authors-list").find('input[type="checkbox"][name^="treated"]:checked').each(function () {

        // use the value of the input in the same row
        grandTotaltreatedCubes += +$(this).closest('tr').find('input[name^="cubicvolume"]').val();

    });
    $("#grandtotaltreatedcubes").text(grandTotaltreatedCubes.toFixed(2));
}
```

Comment: Thanks techfoobar, tried your suggestion but it is not populating the `grandtotaltreatedcubes` span so not sure if 100% right?

Comment: Can your post your html structure too?

Comment: Thanks, I have added this to the question.

Comment: Edited the answer. The selector for checkbox is not `checkbox` but rather `input[type="checkbox"]`

Comment: Hi, what is the opposite of `name^="treated"]:checked` to fetch unchecked values?

Comment: That would be `find('input[type="checkbox"][name^="treated"]').not(':checked')`

Answer (score 2):

First go the parent tr and then using find to find the checkbox in current row and also use checked with DOM object not jQuery object, you can use indexer to convert jQuery object to DOM object.

Change

```
if($("table.authors-list").find('checkbox[name^="treated"]').checked){
```

To

```
if($(this).closest('tr').find('checkbox[name^="treated"]')[0].checked){
```

Comment: Thanks Adil,I understand what you are trying to do but outputting an error now. `TypeError: $(...).closest(...).find(...)[0] is undefined` and `...$("table.authors-list").closest('tr').find('checkbox[name^="treated"]')[0].check...`

Answer (score 2):

`checked` is a property of the actual DOM element, and what you have is a jQuery element. You need to change this:

```
$("table.authors-list").find('checkbox[name^="treated"]').checked
```

To this:

```
$("table.authors-list").find('checkbox[name^="treated"]')[0].checked
                                                         -^- // get DOM element
```

Or more jQuery-ish:

```
$("table.authors-list").find('checkbox[name^="treated"]').is(':checked')
```

Comment: Thanks elclanrs, gave it a go without luck. error on the [0]?

Answer (score 1):

Change the following line

```
if($("table.authors-list").find('input[name^="treated"]').checked){
```

To this

```
if($("table.authors-list").find('input[name^="treated"]').is(':checked')){
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, made the change but not the alert not being triggered so not catching the event?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var grandTotaltreatedCubes = 0;

// Cache the table object here for faster processing of your code..
var $table = $("table.authors-list");

$table.find('input[name^="cubicvolume"]').each(function () {

    // Check if checkbox is checked or not here using is(':checked')
    if ($table.find('checkbox[name^="treated"]').is(':checked')) {
        grandTotaltreatedCubes += $(this).val();
    }
});

$("#grandtotaltreatedcubes").text(grandTotaltreatedCubes.toFixed(2));
```

Comment: Thanks Will, getting error: `$table.find('checkbox[name^="treated"]').is(':checked') {`

Comment: Thanks Will, gave it a go but not working. no errors or output. The if statement is not catching anything?